# How can I ensure that an element will not cause a wrap in a flexbox model?

Tags: css, flexbox

Let's take the following fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wQP8p/

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="name">Super Long Title Because I Want To Do It So</div>
    <div class="extra">OK</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 200px;
}

.preview {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 45%;
    background: red;
}

.name {
    flex: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background: yellow;
}

.extra {
    flex: none;
    background: blue;
}
```

What can I do to keep the ellipsis, and put the blue element at the left of the yellow one ?

Comment: Don't do `flex-wrap: wrap;` if you don't want it to wrap?

Comment: @robertc I want it to wrap after the very first element (the red one)

Comment: Then don't put the first element in the flexbox.  It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: Hm, I guess that I didn't fully understood when to and when not to use multi-line flexbox. What's the rule ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Flexbox doesn't work that way.  If you want the flex items to appear side by side, you have to give them an appropriate flex-basis value that will allow them to fit within the flex container when wrapping is enabled (flex-shrink doesn't do anything here either).

http://jsfiddle.net/wQP8p/2/

```
.name {
    flex: 1 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background: yellow;
}

.extra {
    flex: 1 20%;
    background: blue;
}
```

If the content is dynamic (ie. you don't know the actual width to set), you'll have to add a wrapper around these elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `.extra` div within the `.name` div and apply `display:inline-block;` to the `.extra` class, as shown in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQP8p/1/).

Edit: This may not be a best practice, but it seems to achieve what you are looking for aesthetically.